# C++ Printing out 2D Array via a Function

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

So I'm trying to print out the values inside a 2D array, through a 
function called printArray, but everytime when i try
it saysidentifier "print" is undefined.. I'm sure im doing something 
super super wrong, so any pointers would be greately appreciated :).

Also i'm trying to do it as simple as possible, no pointers or adresses ^^

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;


int A[3][5];

class Matrix {
public:
Matrix() {
    A[0][1] = 5;
    A[1][2] = 3;
    A[2][1] = 2;
    A[3][4] = 10;   
}
void printArray(int height, int width);
};

int main()
{
printArray(A[3][5]);


return 0;
}

void Matrix::printArray(int width, int height) {
for (int i = 0; i < width ; i++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        cout << A[i][y] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: And where the idenitifier print is declared? Do you mean printArray? In any case this call print(A[3][5])  does not make sense.

Comment: Yes i mean printArray, but when i change it its still the same

Edited it.. Still if i name it properly printArray still says its undefined

Comment: Compare the parameter declarations and the supplyed argument.

Comment: `printArray()` is a method of the class `Matrix`. To call this method you need an instance of said class.

Comment: `int A[3][5];` reserves memory for indices 0 ... 2 and 0 ... 4. Accessing `A[3][3]` is undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. Same goes for `A[1][5]`.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printArray` is a member function of a class. So you need an instance of the class to call it on.

```
Matrix m;
m.printArray(3, 5);
```

Comment: Oooh.. yeah i forgot about that hahah, thanks very much ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it says, in your `main()` you're trying to call function `print` that is mentioned nowhere else. Additionally, even if it was, it probably would trigger UB, as you're trying to call it with an unexisting element of the array, to the north-west of it northwestern corner (if you only meant the array itself, you don't need to specify its dimensions, for in the expression context square brackets `[]` signify element index, not the array dimensions).

And your `printArray` accepts two arguments but you're calling it with a single array (non-)element as an argument. In your case, it should be `printArray(3, 5);`.

Comment: `it should be printArray(3, 5);` Not really, you need a `Matrix` instance

Comment: `Matrix`? You mean that class whose default constructor only stores some values in a global object?

Comment: Yep, the class `printArray` belongs to

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `main()`, try:

```
int main()
{
   Matrix a;
   a.printArray(3, 5);
   return 0;
}
```

I believe a better design is possible for this code. Also, please check `A[3][4]`. Your row index shouldn't be more than 2, in this case.

Comment: Yep thanks for pointing that out.. didn't pay attention :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

1. You are calling a method which it does not exist: `print` - that's why the error.
2. Still, if your intention was to call `printArray` you have to be careful because it has 2 parameters, not one(also of different types). Your send a `bidimensional array of type int`, and `printArray` should receive 2 parameters of type `int`.
3. Calling a class's method it should be done by creating an object of that class first and only then, through that object call the method.
4. If you want to call it without creating an object, you should use the keyword `static` - read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm) about it.

I could give you the direct answer, but I think it will help you more if you read from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm). Knowing how to declare a class it's not everything. You also need to learn how to use it.